# Android: Are raw resources stored locally on the filesystem?

Tags: android, resources, apk

I am analyzing an APK, and see a set of .txt resources in the /res/raw/ directory of the application. After installing the application on an emulator, I would expect to see those same files in the /data/data/[app]/files directory, but they do not seem to exist. Where are the raw resources stored? Are raw resources generated at application runtime somewhere else on the filesystem? Or when they are accessed, is it dynamically from the local .apk file? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raw resources (and really, all resources) are bundled in the APK file (this includes files placed in `assets/`), which is why you cannot get to the using `File` handles.  The APK files themselves usually live in the `system/app` directory of the device.

The internal storage location you mentioned (`/data/data/[app]/files`) is where files created with `Context.openFileInput()`, `Context.openFileOutput()`, or `Context.getFilesDir()` are placed.

HTH

Comment: Actually, files placed in the assets folder are not given resource IDs - they are best accessed using the AssetManager.

Comment: Correct, but they are still packed in the APK, which is what I meant.  Guess that wasn't clear...rewording.