# Where are android raw files in storage?

Tags: android, android-resources

I wanna know when we put images or videos in raw directory , where exactly they save and are they accessible out of app ?

Edit : 
I realized internal files can not be reached unless device is rooted or with some apps ... 
now my question is , is it possible to access raw directory files in a rooted device ? if yes so what is best way to secure files and dont let others use then out of app without encrypting files ?

Comment: what do you mean? On your pc?

Comment: You can use the file browser of DDMS to find out

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes !

Comment: Go to your folder where you store your projects from android studio. Then : projectName/app/src/main/res/raw

Comment: @Opiatefuchs sorry ,I  mean after I installed app then connect my phone to pc . or brows phone directories . can I find and access raw files ?

Comment: InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);

Comment: @greenapps thanks but if you attention to question I have asked about accessing out of App !

Comment: Please specify 'out of app'. From where? And why not put that in your post directly?

Comment: @greenapps by browsing  devise directories and files , from phone , pc , ... whatever

Comment: Well those resource files do not lay around on the file system. So you cannot browse them in that way. They were packed with your .apk you know?

Comment: @greenapps thank you a lot , that is what I was asking !

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421001/android-are-raw-resources-stored-locally-on-the-filesystem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [commented by @greenapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960660/where-are-android-raw-files-in-storage#comment74954573_43960660), the resource files do not lie around on the file system. We cannot browse device directories and files from a phone, pc, etc. because they were packed with the .apk.