# Android mobile app drawable icons download

Tags: android, android-install-apk

Android app_resources has various drawable folders for different resolutions like drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, etc...

Does app install gets only drawable-hdpi images when app is installed on a phone with 'hdpi' resolution..?

Or does install on any phone gets all images from all the folders...?

Thank you..

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54468757/edit) your question as to what particular concern are you interested in: download APK size which can differ for apps stores over side-load, or on device expansion.

Comment: definitely size is one of the interesting factors here.. I am interested in the actual workflow of the install process on a phone. Does the APK installer takes care of removing the not needed images or playstore itself has multiple APKs for based on phone resolution and triggers correct download, which will help download size and time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you configure your project

- default apk: yes, everthying
- bundle: it will smartly download accordingly to each device. Bundle made easy the previous dedicated multi-apk

Aditionally there are other more advanced distributions:

- dynamic apps: different modules of the project are dowloaded on demand
- expansion files: for heavy app that need a lot of assets (I think is more than 1 giga or 2). It is downloaded separately than the initial installation
- instant apps: is one or more isolated modules from the project available from api level 21 and above (maybe 23 cant remember now), has to weight less than 5mb and does not need installations the behaviour is comparable to a web page

Answer (score 0):

The APK (which is a zip file) holds the resources, so those aren't unzipped when the app is installed:

See: [Android: Are raw resources stored locally on the filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421001/295004) and [Why does Android keep APK files of installed apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174435/3573).

Google Play Store allows for a number of ways to handle the 'large APK' issue:

[Using Multiple APKs which uses manifest filters and version codes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#HowItWorks)

[Android APK Expansion Files - usually for games exceeding 100MB APK size](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files)

and more recently:

[Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) which requires the use of [Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) and limited to Android 5.0 and higher for split APKs, multi APKs for lower.

and

Google's allowing small native apps to run without install in a 'try now' fashion: [Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/overview) which is also limited to Android 5.0 and up.